# Watson Assistant Dialog - child node not appearing in WhatsApp integrated bot

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp, watson-assistant

Hi I have simple watson assistant bot, works perfectly fine when integrated with slack and web integrated.
When integrated with with whatsapp, the child node doesn't display, it just shows the parent node. Can anyone assistant with displaying child node in my whatsapp Bot?

node js script

```
// Import Modules

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

// Twilio Credentials

const accountSid = '<>';
const authToken = '<>';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ entended: false }));
var env= require('dotenv').config()

// Watson Credentials

var assistant = new watson.AssistantV1({
  iam_apikey: '<>',
  version: '2018-09-20',
  url: '<>'
});
var context1 = {};
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
})
// API

app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request Object");
    var From = req.body.From;
    console.log(From);
    assistant.message({
        workspace_id: '<>',
        input: { 'text': req.body.Body },
        context: context1
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err)
            console.log('error:', err);
        else {
                context1 = response.context;
                var msg = response.output.text[0];
                console.log("message", msg);
                client.messages
                    .create({
                        body: msg,
                        from:'whatsapp:+14155238886',
                        to: From
                    })
                    .then(message => console.log(msg))
                    .done();

    }
    })

});
//PORT Listen 
app.listen(process.env.PORT||8000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running at 8000");
});
```

[image o[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KttRc.png)